# Im not able to get to "/campgrounds/:id/comments/new"

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm doing a  course on Nested Routes. And I'm not able to get past this error

When I go to the path "/campgrounds/59c00fca35776136ee26eb93/comments/new"

I get the error:

*Cannot GET /campgrounds/59c00fca35776136ee26eb93/comments/new*

This is my app.js code

```
    //=========================================================
    //COMMENT ROUTES
    //========================================
    app.get("/campgrounds/:id/comments/new", function(req, res) {

        res.send("this ll be the new comment route");
    });
    app.listen(process.env.PORT, process.env.IP, function(req, res) {
        console.log("Plugging in the Pikachu....");
    });
```

Comment: I copy and pasted your route function directly into my express server just to be sure there weren't any typos, and it worked fine for me. Can you post your entire app.js file?

Comment: @AndrewHarris https://gist.github.com/anonymous/246a908107063cd8dbbc3fae24e47a02

Comment: I just copy and pasted all of that code into a new express server and that route [works totally fine for me](https://imgur.com/a/4TGmT). Which, assuming you're typing in the right URL in your browser, makes me think there's a problem with your environment somehow, not the code.

Comment: damn. ok. let me check. im working within a cloud9 environment. all routes work till now except this one

Comment: @AdarshML How do you sort it out, having same problem

Comment: @AdarshML I know what you are doing, you would be executing in another version, and coding in another, happened with me too.. silly silly mistake

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be one thing here that needs to be done and one thing that should be done:

1. You need to declare the ":id" as you are running your GET call as a variable whose value is equal to `var id = req.params.id`
   This will pull the `"59c00fca35776136ee26eb93"` id value out of the path and parse it into something the computer will recognize.
2. You should declare another variable as the object to send in your res.send() script. i.e. `var message = "id + will be the new comment route"
   res.send(message)`

Hope this helps!

Comment: This code will help me retrieve the "id" value. But i want to get to the "/campgrounds/:id/comments/new" path. From there i can go about working with "id"